# Symfony Route Conditions DSL Context

Tags: php, symfony, dsl, symfony-routing

The short version: What objects do I, the end user programmer, have access to when using Symfony's routing conditions?

The long version: Symfony routes allow you to use [a key named `condition`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html).

```
contact:
    path:       /contact
    controller: 'App\Controller\DefaultController::contact'
    condition:  "context.getMethod() in ['GET', 'HEAD'] and request.headers.get('User-Agent') matches '/firefox/i'"
```

The value of `condition` is code -- it's a Symfony Domain Specific Language (DSL) based on (but not identical to?) the twig templating language syntax.  The [Symfony docs refer to this as "The Expression Syntax"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html).

That much I've been able to glean from the documentation.  What I can't figure out is what object I'll have access to using this DSL?  i.e. in the example above the expression seems to have access to a `context` object and a `request` object.

Are there others?  Are there docs or a place in the source code where I can see what other objects I'd have access to with `condition`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation you are linking](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html) states that only these two objects are available in the expression:

> You can do any complex logic you need in the expression by leveraging
>   **two variables that are passed into the expression**:
>
> context -  An instance of `RequestContext`, which holds the most fundamental information about the route being matched.
>
> request - The Symfony `Request` object (see Request).

(Emphasis mine).

You can see where these objects are injected into the expression on `Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher::handleRouteRequirements()`:

```php
protected function handleRouteRequirements($pathinfo, $name, Route $route)
{
    // expression condition
    if ($route->getCondition() && !$this->getExpressionLanguage()->evaluate($route->getCondition(), ['context' => $this->context, 'request' => $this->request ?: $this->createRequest($pathinfo)])) {
        return [self::REQUIREMENT_MISMATCH, null];
    }

    return [self::REQUIREMENT_MATCH, null];
}
```

The call to `evaluate()` passes both the expression you defined on the `condition` key, and an array with `$context` and `$request`.

Comment: Thank you @yivi!  For some reason I read that that as a description of the specific code sample and NOT as how the system generally behaves.  Too many DSLs I suppose :)